# Google apps script #NAME error when published to web

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just wrote a really small apps script, Which has a custom function to do some minor math.Basically this cell for example B2 takes the value of A1 which auto updates every minute based  on the trigger and does the math. In B2 i just used the custom function directly like this =customFunction(A1).It executes perfectly fine. The problem is when i publish to web, The cell just displays #NAME instead of the return value of the function. As a novice i'm stuck with this for days now. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my custom function

```
function fryBoxesNeeded(){
var boxesSoldPerThousandDollars = 1;
var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var salesRange= sheet1.getRange("B2");
var totalSales = salesRange.getValue();
var totalBoxesNeeded = boxesSoldPerThousandDollars * 
(totalSales/1000);
var boxesRoundOff= ("Total fry boxes 
needed"+""+Math.round(totalBoxesNeeded));
return boxesRoundOff;

}
```

I tried changing the number to a string and displaying, But still the same. I do not want to hard code the cell address in the code. This is what i'm pondering on how to get it done

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "publish to the web" what are you trying to do? I tweaked your formula slightly (see below) and it works find [See this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CmBOBg-Izd9lGdZC1fEYe65RhYQ25w4AHLlvka19Ffo/edit#gid=0).

I'd question the need to use google app scripts given this formula though. One could duplicate the result much faster with a formula. You could use a Let function to almost use the exact same setup as the script. (see example in same spreadsheet.)

### Script Option

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/
function fryBoxesNeeded(totalSales){
  const boxesSoldPerThousandDollars = 1;
  const totalBoxesNeeded = Math.round(boxesSoldPerThousandDollars * totalSales/1000).toString();
  return "Total fry boxes needed "+ totalBoxesNeeded;
}
```

### Formula Approach

```
=let(boxesSoldPerThousandDollars,1,
totalSales,B2,
totalBoxesNeeded,boxesSoldPerThousandDollars*totalSales/1000,
"Total fry boxes needed "&totalBoxesNeeded)
```